# Php: fetching last inserted row on mysql table to use for another mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch the id of the last inserted row from a mysql table using php and use that id to enter a new entry on another table. I have this until now

```
$inductionmethod = $_POST['inductionmethod'];   
$injectionmethod = $_POST['injectionmethod'];   
$dosage = $_POST['dosage'];     
$metric = $_POST['metric'];     
$notes = $_POST['notes'];       

global $db_usr;     

$query = "SELECT MAX( experiment_id ) FROM experiment";     
$prep = $db_usr->prepare($query);   
$lastid = $prep->fetch();

$query ="INSERT INTO experiment_using_methods (experiment_id, induction_method, injection_method, dosage_quantity, dosage_unit, dosage_qualitative)
        VALUES (
        '".$lastid['MAX( experiment_id )']."', # the fetched ID of the corresponding dataset
        (SELECT induction_method_id FROM induction_method WHERE im_name = '".$inductionmethod."'), # name of induction method
        (SELECT injection_method_id FROM injection_method WHERE im_name = '".$injectionmethod."'), # name of the injection method
        '".floatval($dosage)."', # dosage quantity
        '".$metric."', # dosage unit or metric
        '".$notes."' # qualitative dosage - REMOVE??
        )";

$prep = $db_usr->prepare($query);       
$prep->execute();
```

I think I'm getting an error while fetching the MAX( experiment_id) or maybe I'm using it incorrectly on the INSERT statement because if I replace the ".$lastid['MAX( experiment_id )']." part by a number the insert statement works fine. On the other hand I also test the SELECT MAX( experiment_id ) FROM experiment statement on the mysql command line and it also works fine. Am I using fetch and referencing the result value correctly?

Comment: What is `$db_usr`?

Comment: Try `MAX( experiment_id ) as lastinsertid` and later `$lastid['lastinsertid']`

Comment: @PeeHaa that's the database connection. That's working fine since other statements use it too.

Comment: Does $lastid actually contain a key called "MAX(experiment_id)"?  Looks like you're, um, 'mixing metaphors'.  The PHP will be evaluated before the SQL happens ...

Comment: I mean what is it an instance of? PDO?

Comment: why not just use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and assign a variable to it?

Comment: If `LAST_INSERT_ID()` not depends on a table, then you can only use it directly after insert statement, i think

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Changing it to lastinsertid didn't work

Comment: see my answer, thats the bug i thing

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, I'll look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing this is the main issue:

```
$prep = $db_usr->prepare($query);   
$lastid = $prep->fetch();
```

change it to:

```
$prep = $db_usr->prepare($query);   
$prep->execute();
$lastid = $prep->fetch();
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks! I don't know who downvoted your answer but it was correct.

Comment: i had a bug in it, but removed it ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have connection as $con, then for MySQLi Object-oriented:

```
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id; 
}
```

MySQLi Procedural way:

```
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
}
```

PDO way:

```
$con->exec($sql);
$last_id = $con->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: I'm PDO and I tried the lastInsertId function before but it doesn't work because that uses the last inserted entry on any table and I need the last inserted one of a specific table. That's why I use Select Max. But thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: If you see for last inserted id just after your insert query, then it will return the last id the same table.

Comment: @JayPatel I know but the previous insert statement that I need is called from a jquery code that sends data to several insert calls on php so I can't be sure the last one is the one I need.